# Django Rest Framework, is it possible to organize uploaded files by associated user?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm planning out a backend which takes in an email associated with a file upload. Would it be possible to make the backend create a new sub-folder (with the name being the uploaded email address) in my main media folder every time a file was uploaded with a new email, or put files into the corresponding sub-folder?

I've tried to look up any examples of this, but haven't come across any.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed to that by setting the `upload_to` attribute of your `FileField` to a callable as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield) in the docs.

Example

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

# Create user dir if non-existant and return upload path
def upload_path(instance, filename):
    path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, str(instance.user))
    if not os.path.isdir:
        os.mkdir(path)

    return os.path.join(path, filename)


class MyMail(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    attachment = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_path)
```

The attachement is now uploaded to a folder with the user name in your media folder.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!